# Calling destructor function in middle of the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, memory-management, destructor

I have one query regarding object destruction and calling of destructor in middle of the program.

Ex:

```
class ABC: 

    # Initializing 
    def __init__(self): 
        print('Constructor Called') 

    # Destructor 
    def __del__(self): 
        print('Destructor called')

obj = ABC() 
del obj 
# I want destructor to be called here.
# and then print below statement
print("obj deleted")
```

But instead destructor is called at end of the program.

Any help dev?

Comment: When I run this code, I get ```Constructor Called
Destructor called
obj deleted```

Comment: You didn't call `__del__`; you used `del`, which *might* indirectly result in `__del__` being called. Although the object is *eligible* to be garbage-collected, I wouldn't consider it surprising if, for whatever reason, this was delayed until the program completes, and an exiting interpreter doesn't have to do *any* garbage collection. `__del__` simply should not be relied on to be called.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed in the docs for `__del__()` ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)):

> Note `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`’s reference count reaches zero.

If you are trying to "deconstruct" a Python object (and notice how I said so in quotes), I would instead recommend using `__exit__()` with a `with` statement (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)).

To use the `with` statement you define a class with the following methods:

```py
def __enter__(self)
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

A simple example would be the following:

```py
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.stack = list(args)

    def __enter__(self):
        # Example computation here.
        filtered = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), self.stack)
        return list(filtered)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        del self.stack

# Once you leave the 'with' statement, this Bar() object will be deleted for good. 
with Bar("Hello", "World!", 1, 2) as stack:
    print(stack)
```

Though frankly, "deconstructing" an object in Python is almost never needed and in most cases you should program with the intended of staying away from trying to do the job of the [garbage collector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html). Using `del` is one thing, but trying to "deconstruct" an object is another.

Comment: Thank You very much for such a quick and informative answer @Felipe. Your answer really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `__del__` method is called when the reference count of an object reaches 0, or when it is traversed by the garbage collector in case of circular reference. For example, the following:

```
class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Foo has been deleted!')

foo = Foo()
del foo
```

Would properly call the `__del__` method and prints `Foo has been deleted!` because the object assigned to `foo` was only referenced once. Now let's take a look at the following example:

```
class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Foo has been deleted!')

foo = Foo()
foo.self = foo
del foo
```

The `__del__` method won't get called because `foo.self` is keeping itself hostage. It will only be deleted when traversed by the garbage collector. For example:

```
from gc import collect

class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Foo has been deleted!')

foo = Foo()
foo.self = foo
del foo

collect()
```

The `__del__` method will be called, because we told the collector to traverse the pending objects. Not recommended, but you could tell Python to traverse all the queue by setting the thresholds to 1. For example:

```
from gc import set_threshold

set_threshold(1, 1, 1)

class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Foo has been deleted!')

foo = Foo()
foo.self = foo
del foo
```

So every times 1 object gets instantiated, the collector will do its run. But again, not recommended as it can be costly and affect the performances of your code.